# Alternatives to using class attribute value as a method default parameter?

Tags: c++, parameters, default-value

I want to achieve something like this:

```
class C
{
    int m_nVal;
public:
    C(int nVal) : m_nVal(nVal){}            

    void foo(int nVal = m_nVal)
    {
         // use nVal, if provided; otherwise use m_nVal
    }
};

C c(1);
c.foo();  // use 1
c.foo(2); // use 2
```

This is not possible as C++ standard says:

> *a non-static member shall not be used in a default argument*

Options I have are:

(1) Overload `foo()`:

```
class C
{
    int m_nVal;
public:
    C(int nVal) : m_nVal(nVal){}

    void foo()
    {
        // use m_nVal
    }

    void foo(int nVal)
    {
        // use nVal
    }
};
```

(2) Use static member:

```
class C
{
    static int m_nVal;
public:         
    void foo(int nVal = m_nVal)
    {
        // use nVal, if provided; otherwise use m_nVal
    }
};
```

I don't want to make `m_nVal` static member so option 1 seem the only one.

**Are there any other ways to achieve this?**

Comment: One could say that this is what overloads were *made for*.

Comment: Just call foo() in terms of foo(int nval);

Comment: I guess that using a pointer and `nullptr` as a default value is not an option ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are other alternatives if you are willing to change the interface. You can use `boost::optional`:

```
// untested:
void foo( boost::optional<int> val = boost::optional<int>() ) {
    int value;
    if ( val ) value = *val;
    else value = m_val;
    // Now use `value` in the function
}
```

If you cannot use boost, you can write your own nullable wrapper. You just need to store the type (`int`) and a flag that determines whether it is set or not.

The next option is using a pointer to mark that the argument is optional:

```
void foo( int *pval = 0 ) {
    int value = (pval? *pval : m_val);
    // use value from here on
}
```

But the option with the pointer inhibits the use of *rvalues* as arguments to the function (i.e. you need a proper variable to call the function, you cannot do `foo(1)` but rather need to do `int x = 1; foo( &x );`, which is kind of a pain).

Finally you can use your approach of offering two overloads, one that takes the argument and one that doesn't and just forwards to the first:

```
void foo( int val ) {
   // actual implementation
}
void foo() {
   foo( m_val );
}
```

This might actually be the best option...

Comment: Unfortunately, Boost is not the option (not my decision); I like the idea with the pointer but, as you remarked, this interface won't look *natural* to clients (passing pointer instead of the object itself); I will go with the overloads.

Answer (score 3):

The two options aren't equivalent. Making a member `static` shouldn't be a decision made on whether you want to use it as a default to a method or not.

If `m_nVal` is logically bound to the class, and not an instance, make it `static`.

If `m_nVal` is specific to each object of the class, don't, and use the first option.

Comment: Completely agree. `static` wasn't an option from the start. I listed it above just because it solves the problem in general (but not in some particular case where it doesn't fit in a class design).

Comment: @BojanKomazec I would go with overloading, everything else just seems overkill to me.

Comment: Yeah, that seems the most intuitive approach. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Passing default parameter would mean compiler has to pass it. It would mean, for `m_nVal`, the compiler would use `this->m_nVal`. This would, in turn, mean `foo(this->m_nVal);'.

This is what I mean:

```
c.foo(c.m_nVal);  // use 1
```

Which would allow `m_nVal` **private** data to be accessed outside class, and breaks basic C++ rule.

Comment: Access is not **the** problem with that construct, as you can test by making the field public, in which case access is granted but it will not compile either.

Comment: @Ajay This is actually the reason why I started thinking of refactoring the code - `m_nVal` is currently public and I want to hide it. Another thing is that `foo` is most frequently called with `c.m_nVal` as argument so I started thinking about using it as default value...

Comment: Yes, but private and protected are one of the reasons this isnt' allowed.

Answer (score -1):

```
   class C
    {
        int m_nVal;
    public:

        C(int nVal) : m_nVal(nVal){}            

        void foo(int nVal = -1)
        {
        if(nVal == -1)
            nVal = m_nVal;

             // use nVal, if provided; otherwise use m_nVal
        }
    };

C c(1);
c.foo();  // use 1
c.foo(2); // use 2
```

Comment: This is awful, what if I want to call `foo(-1)`? I'd remove this before you start getting downvoted.

Comment: I actually think that in many domains where you know of specific values are not valid can be used as sentries. For example, if the argument is known not to be negative this would be an option. I would not have upvoted either, but +1 to compensate for what might be an option depending on the domain.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas than why isn't the parameter `unsigned int`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas this is very counter-intuitive. Imagine the docs: pass any integer value. Pass `-1` if you want the member `m_nVal` to be used. :|

Comment: The idea is good, but in my case I cannot rely on using hardcoded value for the reason Luchian mentioned. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore : The original question was not to give 'non-counter-intuitive' answer. Otherwise, why does somebody need another solution than simple and 'intuitive' function overloading. And regarding the documentation, it is the same amount of documentation you need in either case. ("If the foo() function is used the member variable m_nVal is used ..bla bla..."). Sorry, there is no escape.

Comment: @Unni actually you don't need to document a default parameter, you can see it in the function signature. And you can see a method overload in the class definition.